# Showing uniform continuity on $f(x)=x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I just wanted to confirm that my proof makes logical sense. I am still in the process of learning epsilon delta proofs and wanted some feedback.

> Show $f(x)=x^2$ is uniformly continuous from $[1,2]$.

Pf: Suppose $\epsilon > 0$. Let $\delta =\frac{\epsilon}{6}$.
Then if $x,z \in [1,2]$ and $\rvert x-z \lvert < \delta$ then $\rvert x-z\lvert \leq 2$ so $-2 \leq x-z \leq 2$.

Now adding $2z$, $2z-2 \leq x+z \leq 2z+2$.

For RHS: The greatest $z$ value is 2 so $2z+2\rightarrow 2(2)+2=6$

For LHS: the smallest $z$ value is 1 so $2z-2\rightarrow 2(1)-2=0$, thus $0\leq x+z\leq6$, i.e. $x+z \leq 6$.

Now since $\lvert x^2-z^2\rvert=\lvert x-z\rvert \cdot \lvert x+z \rvert$ and $\lvert x-z \rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{6}$, then

$$\lvert x^2-z^2\rvert=\lvert x-z\rvert \cdot \lvert x+z \rvert$$

$$<\frac{\epsilon}{6} \cdot 6$$

$$=\epsilon$$

Hence $\lvert x^2-z^2 \rvert < \epsilon$ and since $\delta$ doesn't depend on $z$, $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[1,2]$.

Comment: what happens if $\epsilon < 2$?

Comment: @Gabriel if $0<\epsilon<2$ wouldn't the proof still hold?

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry. I misread something.

Answer (score 2):

$f'(x)$ is bounded in the interval $[1,2]$. So using Mean Value Theorem $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

$f $ is continuous in a compact set. Hence using Heine-Cantor theorem $f$ is automatically uniformly continuous.